# Ansible import_playbook fails with variable undefined error

Tags: ansible

I am trying to conditionally import a playbook by dynamically generating the name of the playbook to import.

I have the following 2 files:

```
root@ubuntu:~/test# ls -ltr
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117 sij   2 12:07 child_playbook_1.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 210 sij   2 12:11 start.yaml
root@ubuntu:~/test#
```

start.yaml:

```
---
- name: main playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        var: "child_playbook"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ var }}"

- import_playbook: "{{ var + '_1.yaml' }}"
  when: var is defined
```

child_playbook_1.yaml:

```
---
- name: child_playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Message from the child playbook"
```

When I execute start.yaml, I get this as output:

```
root@ubuntu:~/test# ansible-playbook start.yaml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! 'var' is undefined
root@ubuntu:~/test#
```

Why is var not seen and why do I get this message?
How to overcome this?

To put things into a bit more perspective, the 'var' variable in start.yaml is being dynamically read which means that the name of the playbook to be imported will also be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a fact defined for localhost (i.e. the only host in the play) in the first play. So it does not exist "globally", only for the given host.

Moreover, imports are made statically at time of playbook parsing (by opposition to includes which are dynamic but to not exist for playbooks).

One could then try to use the var defined for localhost by referencing `hostvars['localhost'].var` but:

- `set_fact` has not yet run since it is an import.
- Moreover `hostvars` is not yet defined at time of import.

Lastly, you are miss-interpreting how a `when` clause is actually working. Basically, the condition is passed to all the tasks contained in your included/imported object. So the imported object must exist. If you use an undefined var to get its name, it will always fire an error.

The only solution I currently see to pass a variable playbook name is to use an extra var on the command line. If you want to be able to 'skip' the import when no variable is defined, you could default to an empty playbook.

Here is a dummy `empty.yml` playbook

```
---
- name: Dummy empty playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
```

For my tests, I used the same child playbook as in your question except I disabled facts gathering not needed here:

```
---
- name: child_playbook
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="Message from the child playbook"
```

The new main playbook `start.yml` looks like this:

```
---
- name: Play written in start.yml directly
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Message from start playbook"

- import_playbook: "{{ var is defined | ternary( var | default('') + '_1.yml', 'empty.yml') }}"
```

Note than even though we use `var is defined` as a condition, `var` will still be interpreted in the ternary filter in all cases (defined or not). So we have to use a default value to make sure we don't have an error when we don't pass a value.

We can now call the playbook with or without an extra var. Here is the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook start.yml 

PLAY [Play written in start.yml directly] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Message from main playbook"
}

PLAY [Dummy empty playbook] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

$ ansible-playbook start.yml -e var=child_playbook

PLAY [Play written in start.yml directly] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Message from main playbook"
}

PLAY [child_playbook] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Message from the child playbook"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: But I think I am not. If you check my code, you will see that the import_playbook is running on the top level and if I put a static name of the playbook to be imported, it works fine. The problem is with dynamically determining the playbook name.

The 'var' variable which was defined prior to import_playbook command is not seen by the import_playbook command but is is correctly seen by the conditional part (when) which is totally strange to me.

Comment: Your error has totally changed since I wrote my answer. Now it is just an undefined var problem. Your original import was running inside a task.

Comment: I sincerely apologize to you - I found the root cause of the initial issue I had so I changed my question to the issue I am facing now.

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve my problem. The variable that you are passing in the command line (var=child_playbook) is in my case being determined through some checks in the code. Actually, what my code is doing is checking current version of software and comparing to the latest available version and if latest version > current version, I run a playbook which has the version in its name - like for example - migration_3.0.0.yml. This is why I need to dynamically determine the name of the playbook to be executed and based on condition "latest > current", run the playbook or not.

Comment: Make a single playbook and pass a variable with the version. What you are trying to do cannot be acheived with a playbook import. Have you considered `import_tasks`/`include_tasks` instead ?